# Default values for Binary fields in Odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

In brief, what is the default value for a *binary field* in Odoo?

More specifically, I'm trying to construct a computed field based on whether or not certain documents have been included in a record (i.e. a sort of status bar on the number of completed fields in the record).

As a toy example if bin1 and bin2 are binary fields and bool is boolean, then my progress would be computed as

```
progress = 100.0 * (1*bool + 1*(bin1 is not None) + 1*(bin2 is not None)) / 3
```

Fortunately, this computation works fine after the record is saved. However, while in *Edit* mode the progress is shown as if it were 2/3.

This brings be to the question of default values for binary fields or any ideas on how to extract the information about whether of not a binary field is filled or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty binary field is `False` a valued one contains `base64` encoded string.

So, before you do your computatation you must do something like:

```
if item.bin_field:
    bin_val = item.bin_field.decode('base64')
```

Your check if failing because you are doing an "identity comparison" so you are basically saying "`is` my value identical to `None`?" instead of checking if is boolean-ly false.